# how to hidden a form in javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I hide a form and display it when a label is clicked?

```
<form id="form1" action="javascript:return true;" name="form1">
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="opt1" id="opt1" 
onclick="show()"><label for="opt1">Option 1</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="opt2" id="opt2" 
onclick="show()"><label for="opt2">Option 2</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="opt3" id="opt3" 
onclick="show()"><label for="opt3">Option 3</label><br>

<div id="droplist">
<select name="opt2-select">
<option value='opt2a'>Option 2A</option>
<option value='opt2b'>Option 2B</option>
<option value='opt2c'>Option 2C</option>
</select>
</div>
</form>

<label id="a" onclick="formenable()">click</label>....

function formenable()
{
var o=document.getElementById("form1");
o.style.visibility="hidden"
}
```

First the form should be hidden default. When the label is clicked the form should be displayed. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form id="form1" action="javascript:return true;" name="form1" style="display:none">
```

---

```
<script>
function cl(obj) {
   div = document.getElementById(obj.id + 'div');
   div.style.display = (div.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
}
</script>

<label id="browser" onclick="cl(this)">Browser</label>

<div id="browserdiv" style="display: none">
    Browser stuff goes here

    <label id="os" onclick="cl(this)">OS</label>

    <div id="osdiv" style="display: none">
       OS stuff goes here
    </div>

</div>
```

With this, when you click on the Browser label, all of the 'os' still will appear/disappear, without having to do any extra hiding/showing. Probably not exactly what you want, but should get you started.

Comment: @thuk: `o.style.visibility = 'visible'` instead of `hidden`.

Comment: @thuk You have hidden the form, and labels are in this form. Conclusion: hiding container hides also the contained elements. You have to move labels somewhere else or reorganize your HTML elements.

Comment: @Marc The problem is the OP wants to hide the form with labels in it and then to show it after labels are clicked (pretty hard considering labels are also hidden with the form).

Comment: Yes, you can add a form inside a div.

Comment: @Dave. a problem http://jsfiddle.net/saravanabalaji/XHV7X/3/  . look at this. when we click "gaming" then "os" a textbox will appear. when we again click os the textbox will disappear. but the problem is when we again click the browser the os and textbox must disappear but os alone disappear.. suggestion ...........

Comment: @Marc a problem http://jsfiddle.net/saravanabalaji/XHV7X/3/  . look at this. when we click "gaming" then "os" a textbox will appear. when we again click os the textbox will disappear. but the problem is when we again click the browser the os and textbox must disappear but os alone disappear.. suggestion ...........

Comment: thuk: nest the "os" section INSIDE the div that contains the "gaming" text. That or modify the "os" handling function to toggle visibility on both the os AND gaming sections when its clicked.

Comment: actually gaming is a label in html. how to include os in that....................

Answer (score 0):

First you have to set CSS style `display` of that form to `none`. Then you can use eg. jQuery's [.show() function](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

CSS styles look like this:

```
form#form1 {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: @Tadeck a problem http://jsfiddle.net/saravanabalaji/XHV7X/3/  . look at this. when we click "gaming" then "os" a textbox will appear. when we again click os the textbox will disappear. but the problem is when we again click the browser the os and textbox must disappear but os alone disappear.. suggestion ...........

Comment: @thuk You did not remove the textbox. My suggestion is, that if you have some constant items that need to be appearing and disappearing, just turn the visibility on and off and keep some kind of hierarchy - it will be easier for you to switch the whole container than every single piece of it.